# How to check if certain data is already in the database?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Im doing a Project for my internship right now and I want to know how to get data from html and from the database and compare if the html data already exists in the database.

I have tried to run it but now I always get the localhost not found error.

**HTML**

**Edit**: The Context and the Database are working fine.

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Starter</title>

    <style>
        p {
            margin-top: 30%;
            margin-left: 20%;
            margin-right: 20%;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 25px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #Code {
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
    </style>



</head>
<body>
    <h1>249765876358312345655</h1>

        <p>

            Eingabe des Maschinen Codes:
            <br />
<!-- Here is the important stuff for this aka HTML data-->
            <input id="Code"
                   name="code"
                   pattern=""
                   size="30"
                   spellcheck="false"
                   title="Maschine Code"
                   value="">
        </p>



    <script>
        var x = document.getElementById("Code");
        x.addEventListener('input', function (event) {
            x = document.getElementById("Code").value;
            let vars = x;
            let digits = vars.match(/^\d{13}(\d{6})\d{2}$/)[1];
            let stringDigits = digits.toString();

            if (stringDigits.length == 6 && vars.length == 21) {

                window.location.href = '/home/Kontrolle';
                document.getElementById("Code").innerHTML = "";
                localStorage.setItem("Code_Kurz", stringDigits);
            }
        }
        );



    </script>

</body>


</html>
```

**Controller**

```
namespace Qualitätskontrolle.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        Boolean newID;

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult StartPage(string Code)
        {
            try
            {
                ViewData["Code"] = Code;
                ApplicationDbContext dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
                var Ergebnisse = dbContext.Result.ToArray();

                for (int i = 0; i < Ergebnisse.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (!Ergebnisse[i].Equals(ViewData["Code"]))
                    {
                        //Create New Page
                        newID = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newID = false;
                    }
                    return View();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }

            return View();
        }
}
```

The result should be that a new site opens depending on wheter its a new Code or an old one.

Comment: which column of `Result` contains the value of `ViewData["Code"]`?

Comment: `object.Equals(object)` is a call which can lie when used improperly. What you need is to check if `Result` table contains a record matching the passed `string Code`. Something like `dbContext.Result.Any(r => r.Code == Code)` (replace `r.Code` with the actual `Result` property).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check with this approach?
Considered that `Code` is the name of the column of the `Result` table in with the value of `Code` is getting saved.

```
var Ergebnisse = dbContext.Result.FirstOrDefault(x => x["Code"] == ViewData["Code"].ToString());
if(Ergebnisse != null)
{
   // Means the item with same code exist
}
else
{
   // Means the item with same code is not exist
}
```

So, the above code will check for the row having a value is code column which is equal to the value that we are giving[ViewData["Code"]], if no such value is found, then null will be assigned to `Ergebnisse`. A simple `if..else` can be used to check the value

Comment: I now get the logic for that but the line: ```C# var Ergebnisse = dbContext.Result.FirstOrDefault(x => x["Code"] == ViewData["Code"].ToString());``` the ```C#x["Code"] ``` does not compile: Cannot apply indexing [] to an expression type "Result".

Comment: @KlausK what is `dbContext.Result`?

Comment: This is the main table for the DB it consits of:                                   
TypenID   int
PruefungenID  int
BildID   int
BauTeilID         string (aka Code)
Date   DateTime
xLabel   string
X   int
YLabel   string
Y   int
FehlerCode  string
Fehlername  string
FehlerGruppe1  string
FehlerGruppe2  string
Result   int
Is that what you meant by it?